# SQL Server - Calculate Student GPA and Insert Into Table Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, group-by

I'm trying to select each student's grades, add them up, and calculate their GPA. Lastly, the Student's name and GPA will be put into a row.

This is what I've started on:

```
Declare @NumClassesTaken int        --Counts number of classes
Declare @GradesEarned decimal(2,1)  --Accumulative Grades
Declare @GPA decimal(2,1)           --@GradesEarned/@NumClassesTaken

Declare @GPATable TABLE ( StudID int, StudGPA decimal(2,1))
```

The table that all my data will be coming from is named [Enrollment], simlar to the below, but with far more data:

```
| StudID  |  SectionNum  |   Grade  |

    123           7           3.0
    123           3           2.0
    702           8           3.5
    702           5           2.5
    664           4           1.0
    664           7           3.5
    992           2           4.0
```

What I'd want the finished product to look like (Grouped By GPA):

```
|  StudID  |   GPA   |

    992        4.0
    702        3.0
    123        2.5 
    664        2.2
```

I'm quite new to SQL so I would really like some assistance with this. It seems pretty simplistic, but I can't really figure out where to start. Is there a way to say for each StudID, sum up all values in the Grade column?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to just use `avg` with `group by`...

Comment: @sgeddes  I have not tried that ( I didn't even think of that). I'm going to look up some syntax for using avg, unless you would like to show me? Sounds like it could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, this is what you're looking for.

```
DECLARE @StudentGrades TABLE(StudentId INT, ClassId INT, Grade DECIMAL(4,2))

-- Sample Entries:
INSERT INTO @StudentGrades
(StudentId, ClassId, Grade)
VALUES (1, 1, 60.0), (1, 2, 70.0), (2, 1, 75.0), (2, 2, 90.0);

-- Check table values.
SELECT * FROM @StudentGrades;

-- This is the report you were looking for.
SELECT StudentId, CONVERT(DECIMAL(4,1), AVG(Grade)) As [GPA]
FROM @StudentGrades
GROUP BY StudentId
ORDER BY GPA Desc; <---- EDITED BY FOXDONUT (GPA in descending order)
```

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Upvoted and Accepted.